# Remapping of some tag synonyms is broken

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

[mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) has the following [synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysql/synonyms): [my-sql](/questions/tagged/my-sql) and [mysql-query](/questions/tagged/mysql-query). However, [mysql-query](/questions/tagged/mysql-query) seems to still have its own [life, questions and followers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql-query). Shouldn't the entire tag and its questions and followers be merged into [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) since it's a synonym?

---

**Update**: interesting, for [java](/questions/tagged/java) the last two [synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/synonyms) [java-api](/questions/tagged/java-api) and [javase](/questions/tagged/javase) are also not fully remapped. For [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) most of the [synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/batch-file/synonyms) are also not fully remapped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This just means the tags need to be merged at some point.

It's not a bug.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding, [mysql-query](/questions/tagged/mysql-query) & [java-api](/questions/tagged/java-api), synonyms process is done by community votes. (batch merging can be done by moderators only, so it moderator didn't involve the tag synonyms process, they won't notice they need to do merging for those tags, right away, isn't it?)

[image]
[image]

New questions will be automatically mapped, IMHO, but for existing questions, moderators need to merge them instead.

Comment: I wonder why existing questions are not automatically merged.