# Tag synonyms do not remap on existing questions

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remapping of some tag synonyms is broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90227/remapping-of-some-tag-synonyms-is-broken)

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686524/php-switch-with-2-values/7686554#7686554), and [its revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7686524/revisions), which until just now was tagged [switch](/questions/tagged/switch) even though that tag is a [synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/switch-statement/synonyms) for [switch-statement](/questions/tagged/switch-statement).

I just edited the question, however, I made absolutely no changes to anything. My edit went through and the tag updated to [switch-statement](/questions/tagged/switch-statement). So it seems all that is needed for a tag to be remapped is a noop edit.

Until this edit, the question didn't appear on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:772035%20%5Bswitch-statement%5D) (my questions and answers to questions tagged switch-statement. You can also see that on the [tags tab of my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/772035/paulp-r-o?tab=tags). I have `15` reputation in [switch-statement](/questions/tagged/switch-statement), so (I think) that implies that the reputation for old tags that have been remapped since the question was last asked / edited are not counting towards badges either. I am sure that when the tags tab updates (I'm not sure what time of day this happens) it will change from `15` rep to `26` to account for that answer, because of my noop edit.

I'm not sure if this happens on all questions with tags that have been remapped or not, but I know it happened on this one. I haven't found a counter-example where it didn't happen or another example of it yet, but I'll be looking out for one.

Comment: Also related: [Should tag synonyms be automatically retagged to the master tag?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131506/should-tag-synonyms-be-automatically-retagged-to-the-master-tag)